# How to handle Special Characters in Upload wizard in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-19.1

How to handle Special Characters in Upload wizard in Oracle APEX from CSV file:

é
è
à
ù
ç
ñ
ö
ë
í
á
ó

[image]

Also, I want to do Transformation of these special char to Alpha chars.

When I upload Excel through CSV, it shows like below:

[image]

[image]

When I do copy/paste it shows like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the file encoding attribute ? When I pick US-ASCII then the characters are not recognized and it shows the characters as �. But when I take a multibyte character eg Unicode UTF-8 it works fine

Comment: Thanks @koen, please see updated image in Body, mine selection is also same, Unicode UTF-8.

Comment: I'd file this question in https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/apex